# getting [] as a result of scraping images from google with dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping

Hello I wanted to scrape images from google, but I get [] as a result of list, I cannot figure it out, please see the code below.

**Main method**

```
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  print('Hello world: ${web_scrapping.calculate()}!');
  await getImageByDom('hyderabad');
  print(imageList);
}
```

**
Method to get images**

```
List imageList;
void getImageByDom(String city) async {
final response = await http.get(
    'https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=$city+city&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiK5_jmqt_uAhWE4oUKHSH-DRYQ2-cCegQIABAA');
var document = parser.parse(response.body);
final elements = await document.getElementsByClassName('bRMDJf');
imageList = elements
    .map((a) => a.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].attributes['src'])
    .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getImageByDom` should return a `List<String>` instead of void.

[Here's a full example](https://repl.it/@serpapi/scrape-google-images-dart)

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  List<String> imageList = await getImageByDom('hyderabad');

  print(imageList);
}

Future<List<String>> getImageByDom(String city) async {
  final Map<String, String> headers = {
    HttpHeaders.userAgentHeader:
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'
  };

  final response = await http.get(
      'https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=$city+city&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiK5_jmqt_uAhWE4oUKHSH-DRYQ2-cCegQIABAA',
      headers: headers);

  if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
    return [];
  }

  var document = parse(response.body);

  final elements = await document.querySelectorAll('.bRMDJf');

  return elements.map((a) => a.querySelector('img').attributes['src']).toList();
}
```

**Output**

```
[data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

But it extracts 1x1 placeholder images because

- Google injects part of rg_meta tags via `_defd` JS function. You need to extract and decode its arguments
- Google Images also contain images directly as HTML tags instead of .rg_meta. You can parse them as usual HTML tags.

Part of Google's JS code from Google Images that injects tags. The first argument defd1 is an ID of the placeholder HTML element to be replaced with contents. The second argument is the encoded HTML string.

```js
_defd('defd1','\x3cdiv  jsaction\x3d\x22IE7JUb:e5gl8b;MW7oTe:fL5Ibf;dtRDof:s370ud;R3mad:ZCNXMe;v03O1c:cJhY7b;\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiGmK7a3szoAhVDB3cKHesrAQoQMygVegQIARBY\x22  data-ictx\x3d\x221\x22 data-id\x3d\x229pyRez7A01yLeM\x22 jsname\x3d\x22N9Xkfe\x22 data-ri\x3d\x2221\x22 class\x3d\x22isv-r PNCib MSM1fd BUooTd\x22 jscontroller\x3d\x22SI4J6c\x22 jsmodel\x3d\x22uZbpBf sB4qxc\x22 jsdata\x3d\x22j0Opre;9pyRez7A01yLeM;27\x22 style\x3d\x22width:283px;\x22 data-tbnid\x3d\x229pyRez7A01yLeM\x22  data-ct\x3d\x220\x22 data-cb\x3d\x220\x22 data-cl\x3d\x220\x22 data-cr\x3d\x223\x22 data-tw\x3d\x22299\x22 data-ow\x3d\x221100\x22 data-oh\x3d\x22619\x22\x3e\x3ca class\x3d\x22wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd\x22 jsname\x3d\x22sTFXNd\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22click:J9iaEb;\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;\x22 data-nav\x3d\x221\x22 tabindex\x3d\x220\x22 style\x3d\x22height:164px;\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22bRMDJf islir\x22 jsname\x3d\x22DeysSe\x22 style\x3d\x22background:rgb(200,194,187);width:292px; height:164px;margin-left:0px; margin-right:-9px;\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;\x22\x3e\x3cimg class\x3d\x22rg_i Q4LuWd tx8vtf\x22 data-src\x3d\x22https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/images?q\x3dtbn%3AANd9GcQ3_h7vxb_72egN52iUj6J4TQs7XajUVhI6BxP_tMepqnFdcGL1\x26amp;usqp\x3dCAU\x22 data-lt\x3d\x22\x22  jsname\x3d\x22Q4LuWd\x22  alt\x3d\x22Jamaican Coffee Companies Devise Plan to Court US Market - OECS ...\x22 \/\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22c7cjWc\x22\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22PiLIec\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22click: gFs2Re\x22\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/a\x3e\x3ca class\x3d\x22VFACy kGQAp\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiGmK7a3szoAhVDB3cKHesrAQoQr4kDegQIARBZ\x22 jsname\x3d\x22uy6ald\x22 rel\x3d\x22noopener\x22 target\x3d\x22_blank\x22 href\x3d\x22http:\/\/oecsbusinessfocus.com\/jamaican-coffee-companies-devise-plan-to-court-us-market\/\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22focus:kvVbVb; mousedown:kvVbVb; touchstart:kvVbVb;\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22sMi44c lNHeqe\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22WGvvNb\x22 \x3eJamaican Coffee Companies Devise Plan ...\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22fxgdke\x22\x3eoecsbusinessfocus.com\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/a\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e')
```

---

Alternatively, you can get images via [Google Images API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial.

[Full example](https://repl.it/@serpapi/scrape-google-images-dart-serpapi)

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io' show Platform, HttpStatus;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;

  final uri = Uri.https('serpapi.com', '/search', {
    'q': 'Coffee',
    'google_domain': 'google.com.pk',
    'gl': 'pk',
    'tbm': 'isch',
    'api_key': envVars['API_KEY'],
  });

  final response = await http.get(uri);

  final convertedResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);

  for (final imageResult in convertedResponse['images_results']) {
    print("""
Title: ${imageResult['title']}
Thumbnail: ${imageResult['thumbnail']}
""");
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Title: New Study Says 25 Cups Is Fine ...fortune.com
Thumbnail: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEQHSv8xWAiRTaXUcY0VbPy2BecsEZ2KpsPQ&usqp=CAU

Title: Positive and Negative Effects of Caffeineaarp.org
Thumbnail: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzN08BEkD0a2Gl7D1vyFUo-jHmhIvlH9FUXQ&usqp=CAU

Title: How is Coffee Decaffeinated?cafedirect.co.uk
Thumbnail: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6Tcm59kufV9EkMEOkf9JErWrj0tSMwOCAIA&usqp=CAU

Title: Colombian Coffee Buzz: What's So Great ...ictcoffee.com
Thumbnail: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQGOKd6N93WdEzpuxpopFJlCXZFqK7YBHofiA&usqp=CAU

Stripped...
```

**Disclosure**: I work at SerpApi.